# Accessing non-PostGIS Postgres instances from QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Does anyone know if it's possible to query tables that are regular Postgres and not PostGIS with QGIS? I have a PostGIS database but want to access tables that aren't spacial - much like reading in a text delimited file.

I've poked around the plugins but to no avail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open tables without geometry via Layer -> Add Layer -> Add PostGIS Layers by checking "Also list tables with no geometry".